# Which places in Earth's crust have the highest concentrations of Iron?

Tags: crust, iron

Where would somebody find the highest concentrations of Iron on or near Earth's surface?

Comment: Where there are iron mines?  But note that a lot of iron deposits (e.g. banded iron formations) are of biological origin.

Comment: Are you asking about a specific geographical location or in which geological environments, regardless of location?

Comment: @Michael Geographical environments mostly. Once you know what kinds of geological environments have high Iron concentrations you know what geographical locations to check.